# Simple bash script that lists all extensions

Tags: linux, bash

I'm looking for a linux bash script that does the following: it takes as input a folder and it outputs all extensions appearing in that folder.

For example
    Script's input: path of folder containing 3 mp3 files and 2 pngs.
    Script's output: "mp3, png"

Comment: Technically speaking linux file names do not have extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Find all extension in current dir by:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f|perl -ne 'print $1 if m/\.([^.\/]+)$/'|sort -u|xargs|sed 's/ /, /g'
```

#### Output

> jpg, log, mp3, mp4, png, we, web, webp

Answer (score -1):

This **should** do the job:

```
cat le
#!/bin/bash
ls $1|sed -nr 's/.*(\..*)$/\1/;s/\.//p'
```

And running it:

```
~/tmp5$ ./le .
csv
txt
```

Brief explanation:
ls $1 # do an `ls` on the passed in name
sed, without printing anything by default (using `-n`) then removes anything on a line before the last `.`, and then removes the period and prints the lines that **had** one.